# How to make repository in laravel

Tags: laravel, repository

I am new to laravel repository. I want to make a repository in laravel. I tried this command `php artisan make:repository UserRepository` but command shows make:repository not found. Please help

Comment: I recommend creating a Repositories folder inside app: `mkdir app/Repositories
` Then create all repos file in it! You can follow some tuts and packages! Like: https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/

Comment: This [package](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository) is useful, it has so many things, Please go to documentation

Answer (score 11):

To use `php artisan make:repository UserRepository`,

install this library https://github.com/jason-guru/laravel-make-repository,

by using the composer command `composer require jason-guru/laravel-make-repository --dev`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Using this package you can create create Repository, Repository with Interface, Service, Trait form command line using php artisan command.

> composer require theanik/laravel-more-command --dev

for create e repository class

> php artisan make:repository UserRepository

it also auto resolve namespace.

Git repo : https://github.com/theanik/laravel-more-command

Answer (score 1):

The repository pattern is not connected to the Laravel framework but it sure made it a lot more popular!

You can install a package made for Laravel 5 to enable it!!

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/repoist-laravel-5-repository-generator?page=1

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the `php artisan make:repo` command is supported for your project?

If you didn't, open a terminal in the root of your project and type the `php artisan` command. Check near the `make` section.

If you see a `make:repository` command, then you can use above command.

If not, then refer to this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/repoist-laravel-5-repository-generator?page=1)

After installing you can use the `php artisan make:repository` command.
I hope it helps,